# GraphApi: can't retrieve likes using time based pagination

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to query the facebook graph api for user's likes and retrieve only those done after a specific timestamp?

Reading this document: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api it seems possible to specify different values for since and until, but if I query the api with something like:

```
userid/likes?since=1397665805
```

I get all the user's likes. Am I doing something wrong or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days spent searching the web and trying the graph api, seems clear that this kind of result can't be achieved.